# Feed python output to whiptail

Tags: python, linux, bash, dialog, whiptail

I would like to use a TUI (text user interface) on a headless linux server by passing output of some PYTHON code to 'whiptail'.   Unfortunately, nothing seems to happen in whiptail.  When I pipe the output from a regular shell script, then whiptail works fine.  Here is what I have:

**data-gen.sh**

```
#!/bin/bash
echo 10
sleep 1
echo 20
sleep 1
...
...
echo 100
sleep 1
```

**$ ./data-gen.sh | whiptail --title "TEST" --gauge "GAUGE" 0 50 0**

I get the below progress bar incrementing as expected.

[image: Whiptail working when piping output from shell script]

---

Now I try to replicate same thing from python:

**data-gen.py**

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import time

print 10
time.sleep(1)
...
...
print 100
time.sleep(1)
```

**$ ./data-gen.py | whiptail --title "TEST" --gauge "GAUGE" 0 50 0**

I get the below progress bar staying at 0%.  No increment seen.  Whiptail does exit once the python program in the background has exited.

[image: No change in progress bar when piping python output]

Any ideas how to get python output to be piped successfully to whiptail ? I have not tried this with dialog; since I wanted to stick to whiptail which is pre-installed on most ubuntu distros.

Comment: It's worth adding `print 20; time.sleep(1)` to `python` script too. On my machine `data-gen.sh` makes progress bar move gradually but `data-gen.py` makes it jump from 0 to 100 immediatelly.

Comment: Try `unbuffer ./data-gen.py | whiptail --title "TEST" --gauge "GAUGE" 0 50 0`

Comment: Or `python -u ./data-gen.py | whiptail --title "TEST" --gauge "GAUGE" 0 50 0`.

Comment: Thank you Arkadiusz ..  python -u ./data-gen.py | whiptail ... worked perfectly.  

Anyway to do this unbuffer output from within the python code itself ?

Comment: I converted commands into answer. You could use `-u` in the shebang.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`man whiptail` says:

> --gauge text height width percent
>
> ```
>           A gauge box displays a meter along the bottom of the
>           box.  The meter indicates a percentage.  New percentages
>           are read from standard input, one integer per line.  The
>           meter is updated to reflect each new percentage.  If
>           stdin is XXX, the first following line is a percentage
>           and subsequent lines up to another XXX are used for a
>           new prompt.  The gauge exits when EOF is reached on
>           stdin.
> ```

That means that `whiptail` reads from `standard input`. Many programs
commonly buffer output when it's not going to the file. To force
`python` to produce unbuffered output you can either:

- Run it with `unbuffer`:

  ```
  $ unbuffer ./data-gen.py | whiptail --title "TEST" --gauge "GAUGE" 0 50 0
  ```
- Use `-u` switch on the command line:

  ```
  $ python -u ./data-gen.py | whiptail --title "TEST" --gauge "GAUGE" 0 50 0
  ```
- Modify the shebang of `data-gen.py`:

  ```
  #!/usr/bin/python -u
  import time
  print 10
  time.sleep(1)
  print 20
  time.sleep(1)
  print 100
  time.sleep(1)
  ```
- Manually flush stdout after each `print`:

  ```
  #!/usr/bin/python
  import time
  import sys

  print 10
  sys.stdout.flush()
  time.sleep(1)
  print 20
  sys.stdout.flush()
  time.sleep(1)
  print 100
  sys.stdout.flush()
  time.sleep(1)
  ```
- Set `PYTHONUNBUFFERED` environment variable:

  ```
  $ PYTHONUNBUFFERED=1 ./data-gen.py | whiptail --title "TEST" --gauge "GAUGE" 0 50 0
  ```

Comment: Did the #!/usr/bin/python -u  modification.  Works great !!  

Somehow unbuffer does not work on my ubuntu 16.04 running in virtualbox.  Manually flushing after each print seems to be a bit of pain.  Since -u is working fine,  I will go with that.

Comment: You could create a wrapper function for that.

Comment: Yes, I could create a wrapper.  But is there a downside to using  the -u flag?

Comment: The downside is that you can add only one option in the shebang line but you can always get away with that by concatenating options like `-us` etc.

Comment: Good info.  Thanks again.   This is first time I have come across the need to add shebang line option.